# Animation Position X AND Y in babylonjs

Tags: meteor, babylonjs

I need help on something could be easy for devs (i'm Ux Designer).

https://github.com/maximebodereau/LeeGee/blob/master/LeeGee/client/functions.js#L86

In this example I move the sphere on position.x BUT i would like to move the sphere on the ressource position.x and position.y.

How to achieve that ?

I you want you could clone the git https://github.com/maximebodereau/LeeGee.
It's a meteor app, so just install meteor and run.

Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are actually doing that - you are running two float animations, on both position.x and position.y.

But to answer your question more generally - Babylon allows you to animate an entire vector3 object. you could set keys with vector3 values (instead of floats) and animate the position (and not position.x or position.y).

You can see a demo here - http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#20PPQV